# SQL Server Optimizer - not working?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've found out the following article about [A More Efficient Method for Paging Through Large Result Sets](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020131201/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/042606-1.shtml)

They say:

> An optimizer trick that can also be used in this scenario is when a
>   single variable is set to a potential list of values, it will get
>   assigned the value of the last item in the list.

And then they provide the following sample:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_PageResults_NAI] 
(
    @startRowIndex int,
    @maximumRows int
)
AS

DECLARE @first_id int, @startRow int

-- A check can be added to make sure @startRowIndex isn't > count(1)
-- from employees before doing any actual work unless it is guaranteed
-- the caller won't do that

-- Get the first employeeID for our page of records
SET ROWCOUNT @startRowIndex
SELECT @first_id = employeeID FROM employees ORDER BY employeeid

-- Now, set the row count to MaximumRows and get
-- all records >= @first_id
SET ROWCOUNT @maximumRows

SELECT e.*, d.name as DepartmentName 
FROM employees e
   INNER JOIN Departments D ON
       e.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
WHERE employeeid >= @first_id
ORDER BY e.EmployeeID

SET ROWCOUNT 0

GO
```

**Based on the above mentioned article I have written the following T-SQL stored procedure:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Find_Programs

    @programId INTEGER

AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @SelectQuery NVARCHAR(2000)

    DECLARE @first_id INTEGER

    SET @SelectQuery = 'SELECT @first_id = bp.program_id FROM program bp WHERE  bp.program_id >= @programId ORDER BY bp.program_id'
    EXECUTE sp_Executesql @SelectQuery, N'@first_id INTEGER, @programId INTEGER', @first_id, @programId

    PRINT 'first_id: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@first_id);

END
```

but when I run `EXEC dbo.Find_Programs @programId = 0` I get no output. It seems like `@first_id` is not changing its value. **Any ideas why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have not specified that `@first_id` is an output parameter- you are passing it *into* sp_Executesql, but not getting it back out.  [This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262499) explains how to use output parameters with sp_Executesql.

Comment: Thank you - this helped me to figured out that the OUTPUT here refers to the output of `sp_Executesql`, not the stored procedure that calls  `sp_Executesql`.